# Changing App Name and Icon for Different Countries in iOS and Android Apps with Same Bundle Identifier

Tags: android, ios, flutter, google-play, app-store

I'm working on an iOS and Android application available in both the US and Germany. Our requirement is to have a different app name and app icon for each country while keeping the same bundle identifier. The app is already published on the Apple App Store and Google Play Store. When we release updates, we need the app name and icon to change dynamically based on the user's location (Germany or US).

We've conducted research and discovered that some apps can achieve the localization of the app name and icon. However, we're uncertain whether these changes are tied to the device's language settings. In our case, we require a solution that ensures the app name and icon remain consistent even if the user changes the language on their device.

Specifically, we're looking for information on:

How to dynamically change the app name and icon based on the user's country (not locale) in both iOS and Android apps.

Any best practices or considerations when making these changes, especially for apps already available on the App Store and Google Play Store.

Are there any Apple App Store or Google Play Store guidelines or limitations we should be aware of when implementing this feature?

We appreciate any insights or references that can help us accomplish this country based the app name and icon while maintaining the same bundle identifier for our iOS and Android applications. Thank you!

Comment: You can't know the user's country. On iOS you can localise your app name and it will be shown according to the device locale. The app icon cannot be localised on iOS.  You can have an alternate app icon but your app would need to select that after the first launch.

Answer (score 0):

You can create different files in res folder, one will cater to US and one will cater to Germany. Localizatoin will determine which file to use.
Use this link
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization

If there is any solution to your specific problem it'll be here.